# Would staying as a guest at a friend's affect my visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, student-visa

I had a one-year student visa to study at a university in Scotland. I lived there first in a rented accomodation for 5 months and then as a guest at my friend's for five as she was going through an emotional crisis and begged me to move into her association flat with her, free of rent.

Seeing this as a financial opportunity  and emotional support for my friend I agreed. I didn't pay rent but I did pay all the bills and food expenses so it was almost the same amount.

Now my one-year visa has ended and I am back in my country. I was out before my visa ended. When I moved in with my friend I had informed the council and university, so I don't think it was a problem.

I have gotten a progression into a three year course and I am applying for a visa again from my home country. I have the required funds in my account and meet all the requirements for the visa.

I was wondering if my living as a guest with my friend would cause them to reject me. Because I have the money and this time I am renting a flat for a whole year. Even if I had rented an association flat it was not against the law but I didn't, I was just a guest making sure my friend was fine. I have never ever had an overdraft or any kind of debt.

Even if I'm abroad I'm still paying all my contracts.

Comment: @pnuts the question being if UKVI would interpret the OP's living in a council flat as having accessed welfare or public funds, which is a forbidden activity for T4's. Secondarily if the host had permission from the council estate to take in lodgers.

Comment: @pnuts yeah, but the tertiary issue: *"...I did pay all the bills and food expenses..."*   :) It's something for Expats :)